# Using .FromAsync Task Status= WaitingForActivation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, scheduled-tasks, task-parallel-library, task

I am trying to send url requests and get responses back asynchronously, but when I use the .fromAsync method with the .ContinueWith method the task status never changes from WaitingForActivation to running. I have tried using task.Start() but it can not be used with ContinueWith. How would I go by changing the tasks status to running in my code?

```
public void pageCheck(){
    IAsyncResult asyncResult;
    Uri uri = new Uri(TempURL); //TempUrl is assigned a string beforehand
    HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    try{
        Task<WebResponse> task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
            myReq.BeginGetResponse,
            asyncResult => myReq.EndGetResponse(asyncResult),
            (Object)null);

        task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                var responseCode = (HttpWebResponse)t.Result;
                ReadStreamFromResponse(t.Result);
                if(responseCode.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK){
                    //updatestatus
                    reponseCode.Close();
                }
            }
        );
    }
    //catch exceptions
}

private String ReadStreamFromResponse(WebResponse response) {
     StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
     string str = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
     return str;
 }
```

Comment: How and where are you checking the task's status?  Is there are lot of other things happening at this point in time in your process?

Comment: @ReedCopsey I am using the Locals feature in the Debugging tab in VS2010 to check the status. Also, I check the status after it is created and after the continueWith method that I call. There is not much happening other than that, I created a List consisting of urls and I am going through each one with a for each loop. I will try to make the changes that you made below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Task.Factory.FromAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321427.aspx) automatically schedules the task.  From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321427.aspx):

> The beginMethod delegate is started on the thread that FromAsync is running on. This method throws any exceptions thrown by the beginMethod.

You would typically write this without lambdas:

```
Task<WebResponse> task = Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
        myReq.BeginGetResponse,
        myReq.EndGetResponse,
        null);
```

If you're using .NET 4.5 and C# 5, you cna use [`WebRequest.GetResponseAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync.aspx) directly, as well.

Comment: When I try this it tells me the call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync ....

Comment: It seemed to work Thank You. Its status says Faulted which I looked up and it said it means that it completed due to an unhandled exception which was an AggregateException. I will try to figure this out.

Comment: @DeVonte You'll need to check the task's exception within the ContinueWith statement to see what's causing the fault.

Comment: The error seems to be at the line: var responseCode = (HttpWebResponse)t.Result;
AggregateException was unhandled by the user code

Comment: @DeVonte When you fetch the `Result` property, Task will reraise any exceptions that occurred wrapped in an AggregateException. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx

Comment: I was able to print the error message but all it states is that one or more errors occured. I was a little confused on how to handle my situation with the link you gave, particulary on how to catch the aggregateexception correctly and read the innerexceptions.  Would happen to know any other links that would be able to help me with this issue?

Comment: @DeVonte The link I pasted is the best - the inner exceptions will have the "real" exception

Comment: I believe I understand the concept now Thank you